# A 2SLS when the instrumented variable has two interactions in the model

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I am using `ivreg` and `ivmodel` in `R` to apply a 2SLS.

I would like to instrument one variable, namely $x_1$, present in two interaction terms. In this example $x_1$ is a factor variable. The regression is specified in this manner because the ratio between $a$ and $b$ is of importance.

$$y = ax_1 x_2 + bx_1x_3 + cx_4 + e$$

For this instrumented variable I have two instruments $z_1$ and $z_2$. For both the following causal diagram is applicable (Z only has an indirect effect on Y through X).

[image]

What is for this problem the correct way to instrument $x_1$?

## In the data

Translated to some (fake) sample data the problem looks like:

$$happiness = a(factor:income) + b(factor:sales) + c(educ) + e$$
$$=$$
$$(y = ax_1 x_2 + bx_1x_3 + cx_4 + e)$$

Where the instrument $z_1$ is `urban` and $z_2$ is `size`. Here I however become to get confused about how to write the regression.

## For the first stage:

What is my dependent variable here?

## For the second stage, should I do:

$$happiness = a(urban:income) + b(urban:sales) + c(educ) + e$$
$$happiness = a(size:income) + b(size:sales) + c(educ) + e$$

Or should I just do:

$$happiness = urban*(a:income+b:sales) + c(educ) + e$$
$$happiness = size*(a:income+b:sales) + c(educ) + e$$

Nevertheless, how should I specify this in `R` ?

```
library(data.table)
library(ivmodel)
library(AER)
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "BEL", "GER")
urban = c("A", "B", "C")
indust = c("D", "E", "F")
sizes = c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- 2
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
                    country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                    some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                    Factor = sample(0:5, 6), 
                    industry = rep(sample(indust, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    urbanisation = rep(sample(urban, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    size = rep(sample(sizes, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    income = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                    Y_Outcome= round(rnorm(10,100,10),2),
                    sales= round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                    happiness = sample(10,10),
                    Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                    Age = sample(100,100),
                    educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))        
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                         # Creates a unique ID     
DT <- as.data.frame(DT)
```

To make it slightly easier for someone to help who is not familiar with the packages, I have added how the structure of the two packages I use looks.

The structure of the second stage of `ivreg` is as follows:

```
second_stage <- ivreg(Happiness ~ factor:income + factor:sales + educ | urban:income + urban:sales + educ, data=DT)
```

The structure for `ivmodel` is:

```
second_stage<- ivmodel(Y=DT$Happiness,D=DT$factor,Z=DT[,c("urban","size")],X=DT$educ, na.action = na.omit)
```

Any help with figuring out how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a causal diagram to your question, please?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I am not very familiar with using causal diagrams, but I noticed that my example was very unclear. Did I by improving the example perhaps take away your confusion? If not, could you tell me what exactly is unclear? I will then try to make that clear using a causal diagram.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I have added a diagram:)

Comment: Causal diagrams can make a LOT of causal concepts much clearer - I would always start with them. Your diagram still leaves me with a couple questions: 1. Is $Y$ the effect variable? 2. Is $X$ the causal variable? 3. What is the big red X in your diagram? One comment: your diagram is not the usual setup for 2SLS. Instrumental variables can be useful for certain diagrams, but other techniques, such as the backdoor adjustment or the frontdoor adjustment formulas, are oftentimes more useful.

Comment: Y is the dependent/effect variable. The main point is that the z, provide an exogenous shock to x. Furthermore, the z do not affect y other than through x (hence the red cross). The correlation between the z and x should therefore lead to an exogenous change in y. Which I assume answer the question what the causal effect of x on y is. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: So actually, the best causal diagram would simply be $Z\to X\to Y,$ right? When a variable does not affect another, you simply don't have any edges between them. In this case, I do not see why 2SLS is necessary; there is no confounding, because there is no backdoor path from $X$ to $Y.$ 2SLS is more for a confounding situation, particularly when there is an unmeasured backdoor path from $X$ to $Y.$

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AdrianKeister. I get your point, but this post is just a simplified example I made up. The actual situation is a bit more complicated. As a results, I would really like to stick to the 2SLS. Is there anything you can do for me with regard to answering the main question?

Comment: The standard 2SLS would be this: $y=r_1z+\varepsilon$ and $x=r_2z+\varepsilon.$ Then the ratio $r_1/r_2$ provides the coefficient $\alpha$ of the true causal effect of $X$ on $Y.$ So the IV $z$ is always on the RHS of all the regressions. I'm not an R guy, so I can't help with your R syntax.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, that part is clear to me. But how do I deal with the instrumented variable $x_1$ being an interaction with two other variables $x_2$ and $x_3$? My suggest model is $y=ax_1x_2+bx_1x_3+cx_4+e$ . My problem is not how to carry out a 2SLS. My problem is how to carry out this particular 2SLS, The first stage would suggest that my dependent variable (or variables) would be interaction term(s).. My question is how to deal with that (without losing the information from the factors).

Comment: Everything's clearer in causal diagrams. I would STRONGLY recommend drawing up as accurate and full a causal diagram as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an endogenous variable $x_1$ which is a factor, let's say that it takes 6 values ($x_1 = ``a",...``f")$. In your model it enters with an interaction with variables $x_2$ and $x_3$. Therefore your model is equivalent to

$$y = a_11_{(x_1=``a")}x_2+...a_51_{(x_1=``f")}x_2+b_11_{(x_1=``a")}x_3+...b_51_{(x_1=``f")}x_3+cx_4+e$$

where $1_{(x_1=``a")} = 1$ if $x_1=``a"$ and zero otherwise.

So it has $2\times6$ endogenous variables (the 12 interactions) and you need at least 12 instruments.

In your example you have an endogenous variable $factor$ and two good instrumental variables $urban$ and $size$. If they are good instuments for $factor$ then their interaction with $income$ and $sales$ is good for the same interaction with the instrumented variable. **But still you need at least 12 instruments**.

The first step of the 2SLS will be a OLS regression where the dependent variables are the 12 endogenous interactions $1_{(x_1=``a")}x_2,...1_{(x_1=``f")}x_3$ and the independent variables are all the instruments and the rest of the exogenous variables.

The second step is another OLS regression where the dependent variable is the original one and the independent variables are the exogenous variables + the fitted values of the first step.

Now, following your code example, suppose your instrument is also a factor, let's say it has 6 levels, you'll have enough variables to estimate it. In your code the variable `Factor` is numeric, so let's make it a factor first.

```
DT$Factor = as.factor(DT$Factor)
```

Based on your code, without instruments:

```
lm(happiness ~ Factor:income + Factor:sales + educ,data=DT)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            educ  Factor0:income  Factor1:income  Factor2:income  Factor3:income  Factor4:income  Factor5:income   Factor0:sales  
   4.46555         3.25149        18.18265       -19.68570       -16.71225       -38.04578       -19.68150         2.98939        -0.10307  
 Factor1:sales   Factor2:sales   Factor3:sales   Factor4:sales   Factor5:sales  
  -0.16310        -0.03131        -0.12445        -0.14503        -0.08158
```

Now, in a 2SLS model using `ivreg` with the two instruments you provided:

```
ivreg(happiness ~ Factor:income + Factor:sales + educ | urbanisation:income + urbanisation:sales + size:income + size:sales + educ, data=DT)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            educ  Factor0:income  Factor1:income  Factor2:income  Factor3:income  Factor4:income  Factor5:income   Factor0:sales  
    -6.690           8.736        -296.010         292.081          36.372        -183.167        -231.191         712.253          -1.522  
 Factor1:sales   Factor2:sales   Factor3:sales   Factor4:sales   Factor5:sales  
     2.428              NA              NA              NA              NA  

Warning message:
In ivreg.fit(X, Y, Z, weights, offset, ...) :
more regressors than instruments
```

You see that it can only estimate 8 endogenous variables, this is because we provided 8 instruments: `urbanisation` has 3 levels (hence 6 interactions) + 2 interactions for `size`.

Now consider using the variable `urbanisation2` with 6 levels:

```
DT$urbanisation2 = rep(sample(c("A", "B", "C","D","E","F"), length(panelID), replace = T), each = n)

ivreg(happiness ~ Factor:income + Factor:sales + educ | urbanisation2:income + urbanisation2:sales + size:income + size:sales + educ, data=DT)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)            educ  Factor0:income  Factor1:income  Factor2:income  Factor3:income  Factor4:income  Factor5:income   Factor0:sales  
     4.513e+00       3.321e+00       6.329e+00      -1.802e+01       1.045e+01      -1.154e+02       6.208e+01      -3.196e+01      -8.905e-03  
 Factor1:sales   Factor2:sales   Factor3:sales   Factor4:sales   Factor5:sales  
    -1.706e-01      -1.730e-01       2.692e-02      -3.410e-01      -3.671e-02
```

Now it works because you have enough instruments.

Comment: Hey @Ale, thank you for your answer! I'm going to try to run this on my actual data. What does it mean for the dependent variable in my first stage (which would normally be the instrument) in this case? I assume that ivreg will just treat the factor interaction as continuous in the first stage?

Comment: Wait, in your example `DT$Factor` was a numeric variable. If the endogenous variable is a factor with 5 levels then is like having 5 variables of interaction for each level, ex: $a_1(x_1="a")*x_2+...+a_5(x_1="e")*x_2$, if all these are endogenous you need at least as many instruments. In the 1st step all endogenous interactions are the dependent variables on the exogenous + instruments.

Comment: I edited the answer to take into account botha theory and practice

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to take a look first thing in the morning!

Comment: Good morning @Ale, thank you so much for your help. This clears a lot of things up. Especially that the instrumented variable is the whole interaction term. I have one small remaining questions. I assume that "under the hood" of `ivreg`, the first stage independent variables (the instrumented variables) will be treated as continuous (even though they are actually factor variables) right? So I probably need to run a separate `mlogit` or something to see if the first stage result is not biased right?

Comment: Hi, I guess yes. In the first step each $1_{(x_1=``a")}x_2$ is actually $x_2$ with zeros where $x_1 \neq a$. You get the same coefficients of `ivreg` if you do it manually with the two steps `lm()`

Comment: Dear Ale, thanks again for your help on this one. I have a small question. You write: `In your example you have an endogenous variable factor and two good instrumental variables urban and size. If they are good instuments for factor then their interaction with income and sales is good for the same interaction with the instrumented variable. But still you need at least 12 instruments.` Do you have any official reference for this that I can refer to when I claim this?

Comment: If an instrument is good (relevant and exogenous) also its interaction with an exogenous variable should be good, you can try the same checks you did on the instrument itself. You need 12 instruments because categorical variables with $m$ values are treated with $m-1$ binary variables.

Comment: Ah because I am assuming that `sales` and `income` are exogenous... Got it, sorry! Thank you for your quick response.